# Rotation in static transform publisher

Tags: ros, static-transform-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a basic question. I'm a little bit confused how should I assign one of my last three argument below in order to flip or rotate by 180 degree of the z-axis of the parent frame while the other axis remains unchanged. I mean, the z-axis of the frames are opposite in their directions.  I wonder if, there is any possibility that I can simply negate the value of the z-axis. The problem I'm currently having is that, if I apply/set a rotation of 180 deg(in which 3.142) about y-axis, then, x-axis will be negated and the same goes to if a apply it about x-axis.

```
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_link_to_laser"  
  args="0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 /base_link /laser  40" />
```

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12759/rotation-in-static-transform-publisher/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2012-01-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You cannot do that.

The reason is that when you just flip the z-axis you will transform a right-handed into a left-handed coordinate system, thus not having a simple euclidian transform, but actually a mirroring.

The other question would be: Why do you want to do that? Judging from the name, you just want a base link to laser transform, which shouldn't require this. Maybe you just got the wrong idea about how you want to transform?

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-01-26**:
Yes, but I think you have the wrong idea of what you want to do. Switching only one axis would mean that the physical laser is mirrored, which is impossible. If you have a photo or drawing of your robot/the frames involved, it should be simple to give you the correct transform.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-01-25**:
Oh really, there's no way at all. The idea is to specify the laser frame with respect to the base_link.